# Chess game for two human players

Tags: performance, c, chess, sdl

I'm relatively new to programming, as in my second semester of college. To practice C, I started work on a chess game. I'm wondering if there are ways I could improve my code, make it look more professional, or reduce some blocks of inefficient code. I have more ideas on things to add to the game to make it more user-friendly and improve performance, but I want to make sure I'm going in the right direction so far.

This is my first big project that's more than a simple console program.

```
// Chess V1.0
// Kegan
// January 2022
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct GraphicsComponents {
    SDL_Window* window;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer;
    SDL_Surface* surface;
    SDL_Texture* texture;
    SDL_Rect rect;
}gc;

void drawBoard(gc*, int); 
void updatePieces(gc*, int[8][8], int, const char*[12]); 
int findMousePosX(int[8][8], int, int, int, SDL_Event);
int findMousePosY(int[8][8], int, int, int, SDL_Event);

int main(int argc, char* args[]) {
    const int originalTileSize = 32;               // Original sprites are 32 * 32 pixels
    const int scale = 3;                           // Scale to increase size of sprites on the screen
    const int tileSize = originalTileSize * scale; // Each sqaure is 96 * 96 pixels
    const int boardSize = tileSize * 8;            // Width/length of the board based on the size of each sprite

    // Keeping track of the board could be more optimized
    int board[8][8] = {
        8, 7, 9, 10, 11, 9, 7, 8,
        6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,
        12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12,
        12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12,
        12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12,
        12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 3, 1, 2
    };

    int mouseX = 0;
    int mouseY = 0;
    
    bool madeSelection = false; 
    int selectedPiece = 0;

    const char* spritePath[12] = {
        "./sprites/chess_00.png", // light pawn
        "./sprites/chess_01.png", // light knight
        "./sprites/chess_02.png", // light rook
        "./sprites/chess_03.png", // light bishop
        "./sprites/chess_04.png", // light queen
        "./sprites/chess_05.png", // light king
        "./sprites/chess_06.png", // dark pawn
        "./sprites/chess_07.png", // dark knight
        "./sprites/chess_08.png", // dark rook
        "./sprites/chess_09.png", // dark bishop
        "./sprites/chess_10.png", // dark queen
        "./sprites/chess_11.png"  // dark king
    };
    
    gc graphics; 
    gc* graphicsPtr = &graphics;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG);
    SDL_Event event;

    graphics.window = SDL_CreateWindow("Chess!", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, boardSize, boardSize, 0);
    graphics.renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(graphics.window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);

    drawBoard(graphicsPtr, tileSize);
    updatePieces(graphicsPtr, board, tileSize, spritePath);
    
    // Change later to break loop
    while (1) {
        if (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            switch (event.type) {
            case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
                mouseX = findMousePosX(board, mouseX, tileSize, boardSize, event); // Temporary solution. Update later. // Updated. Works better. Could be more optimized?
                mouseY = findMousePosY(board, mouseY, tileSize, boardSize, event); // ^
                break;
            case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if (madeSelection == false) {
                    selectedPiece = board[mouseY][mouseX];
                    board[mouseY][mouseX] = 12; // Sprite of moved piece is not rendered in original position
                }
                else if (madeSelection == true) {
                    board[mouseY][mouseX] = selectedPiece;
                }
                break;
            case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                if (madeSelection == false) {
                    madeSelection = true;
                }
                else if (madeSelection == true) {
                    drawBoard(graphicsPtr, tileSize);
                    updatePieces(graphicsPtr, board, tileSize, spritePath);
                    madeSelection = false;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    SDL_DestroyTexture(graphics.texture);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(graphics.renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(graphics.window); 
    IMG_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}

void drawBoard(gc* graphics, int tileSize) {
    // Load and render the sprites for the alternating tiles
    // This could be more optimized / written better
    char* path = { '\0' };
    
    SDL_RenderClear(graphics->renderer);

    for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
            if (y % 2 == 0) {
                if (x % 2 == 0) {
                    path = "./sprites/chess_12.png";
                }
                else {
                    path = "./sprites/chess_13.png";
                }
            }
            else if (y % 2 == 1) {
                if (x % 2 == 0) {
                    path = "./sprites/chess_13.png";
                }
                else {
                    path = "./sprites/chess_12.png";
                }
            }
            graphics->surface = IMG_Load(path);
            graphics->texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(graphics->renderer, graphics->surface);
            SDL_FreeSurface(graphics->surface);

            graphics->rect.x = (x * tileSize);
            graphics->rect.y = (y * tileSize);
            graphics->rect.w = tileSize;
            graphics->rect.h = tileSize;
            SDL_RenderCopy(graphics->renderer, graphics->texture, NULL, &graphics->rect);
        }
    }
    SDL_RenderPresent(graphics->renderer);

    return;
}

void updatePieces(gc* graphics, int board[8][8], int tileSize, const char* spritePath[12]) {
    // Load and render the pieces according to their position in the board[][] array
    // This could be more optimized by creating a separate function for moving a single piece
    for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                if (board[y][x] == i) {
                    if (board[y][x] < 12) {
                        graphics->surface = IMG_Load(spritePath[i]);
                        graphics->texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(graphics->renderer, graphics->surface);
                        SDL_FreeSurface(graphics->surface);
                        
                        graphics->rect.x = (x * tileSize);
                        graphics->rect.y = (y * tileSize);
                        graphics->rect.w = tileSize;
                        graphics->rect.h = tileSize;
                        SDL_RenderCopy(graphics->renderer, graphics->texture, NULL, &graphics->rect);
                    }
                }
            }               
        }
    }
    SDL_RenderPresent(graphics->renderer);

    return;
}

int findMousePosX(int board[8][8], int mouseX, int tileSize, int boardSize, SDL_Event event) { 
    // Convert the raw mouse position to the chess board square the cursor is inside of
    int rawPosX = event.motion.x;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < boardSize; i += tileSize) {
        if ((rawPosX >= i) && (rawPosX < (i + tileSize))) {
            mouseX = (i / tileSize);
        }
    }
    printf("X %d, ", mouseX);

    return mouseX;
}

// This function is technically redundant. Consider attempting to merge this with the above function
int findMousePosY(int board[8][8], int mouseY, int tileSize, int boardSize, SDL_Event event) {
    // Convert the raw mouse position to the chess board square the cursor is inside of
    int rawPosY = event.motion.y;

    for (int i = 0; i < boardSize; i += tileSize) {
        if ((rawPosY >= i) && (rawPosY <= (i + tileSize))) {
            mouseY = (i / tileSize);
        }
    }
    printf("Y %d\n\n", mouseY);

    return mouseY;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Reducing maintenance burden:

> ```
> void drawBoard(gc*, int); 
> void updatePieces(gc*, int[8][8], int, const char*[12]); 
> int findMousePosX(int[8][8], int, int, int, SDL_Event);
> int findMousePosY(int[8][8], int, int, int, SDL_Event);
> ```

We could avoid having to maintain these declarations by moving the function definitions here instead.

---

### Declare variables as locally as possible:

> ```
> int mouseX = 0;
> int mouseY = 0;
>
> bool madeSelection = false; 
> int selectedPiece = 0;
> ...
> gc graphics; 
> gc* graphicsPtr = &graphics;
> ...
> SDL_Event event;
> ```

It's reasonable to put the constants at the top of `main()`, but we should declare most variables as close to the point of use as possible. All of the variables above could be declared at least a few lines lower down, closer to where they are used. `event` could be inside the main loop.

Taking the address of an object is a common thing in C so we don't need really the `graphicsPtr` variable; it's more typing and conveys less meaning:

```
drawBoard(&graphics, tileSize);
```

---

### Use enums to give meaning to values:

> ```
> int board[8][8] = {
>     8, 7, 9, 10, 11, 9, 7, 8,
>     6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,
>     12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12,
>     12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12,
>     12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12,
>     12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12,
>     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>     2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 3, 1, 2
> };
> ```

We should use an `enum` to give each piece a name and make the meaning obvious. Using "magic numbers" like the above is more error-prone, and involves more work for the programmer looking up the values.

It might also be more convenient to separate the piece and color information into two separate variables in a `Piece` struct, something like:

```
enum PieceType { Pawn, Knight ... };
enum PieceColor { Light, Dark };

struct Piece { enum PieceType type; enum PieceColor color; };
```

And then we could declare the board as an array of `Piece`s instead of `int`s.

---

### Check for errors:

> ```
> SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
> IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG);
>
> graphics.window = SDL_CreateWindow("Chess!", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, boardSize, boardSize, 0);
> graphics.renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(graphics.window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
> ```

These function calls can all fail. We need to check that and handle the error instead of just carrying on. Since we're in the main() function, the simplest thing to do would be to print an error message, and `return EXIT_FAILURE;`.

---

### Simplify input handling:

> ```
>         switch (event.type) {
>         case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
>             mouseX = findMousePosX(board, mouseX, tileSize, boardSize, event); // Temporary solution. Update later. // Updated. Works better. Could be more optimized?
>             mouseY = findMousePosY(board, mouseY, tileSize, boardSize, event); // ^
>             break;
>         case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
>             if (madeSelection == false) {
>                 selectedPiece = board[mouseY][mouseX];
>                 board[mouseY][mouseX] = 12; // Sprite of moved piece is not rendered in original position
>             }
>             else if (madeSelection == true) {
>                 board[mouseY][mouseX] = selectedPiece;
>             }
>             break;
>         case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP:
>             if (madeSelection == false) {
>                 madeSelection = true;
>             }
>             else if (madeSelection == true) {
>                 drawBoard(graphicsPtr, tileSize);
>                 updatePieces(graphicsPtr, board, tileSize, spritePath);
>                 madeSelection = false;
>             }
>             break;
>         }
> ```

`SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` and `SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP` also make the mouse position (and various other data) available in the event struct. So it might be neater to get the position when we get a mouse button event, rather than a mouse motion event.

When testing a boolean variable, we don't need to compare to `true` or `false` to produce a boolean value; it's already a boolean! Also, we don't need an `else if` to check the opposite condition:

```
if (!madeSelection) {
    ...
}
else {
    ...
}
```

I haven't run the program, but the code for selecting and moving a piece looks a bit suspicious. Is it supposed to be a "click and drag" style movement? Or a click once to select, and click again to move? Either way, I suggest grouping the selection variables (`madeSelection`, `selectedPiece`) into a single struct, and moving the logic of selecting a piece into a separate function.

So for a drag-to-move we'd get something like:

```
        case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if (!selection.active)
            {
                int mouseX = findMousePosX(...);
                int mouseY = findMousePosY(...);
                selectPiece(board, &selection, mouseX, mouseY);
            }
        case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            if (selection.active)
            {
                int mouseX = findMousePosX(...);
                int mouseY = findMousePosY(...);
                movePiece(board, &selection, mouseX, mouseY);
            }
```

Note that we shouldn't be doing rendering inside the event / update logic. It should be done once per frame, at the end of the frame. While we could use a boolean flag to avoid "unnecessary" rendering when nothing has changed, it wouldn't really help us: we're still using a "busy" waiting loop while polling input from SDL.

---

### Simplifying mouse position:

> ```
> int findMousePosX(int board[8][8], int mouseX, int tileSize, int boardSize, SDL_Event event) { 
>     // Convert the raw mouse position to the chess board square the cursor is inside of
>     int rawPosX = event.motion.x;
>     
>     for (int i = 0; i < boardSize; i += tileSize) {
>         if ((rawPosX >= i) && (rawPosX < (i + tileSize))) {
>             mouseX = (i / tileSize);
>         }
>     }
>     printf("X %d, ", mouseX);
>
>     return mouseX;
> }
> ```

It doesn't look like we need to pass `board` or `mouseX` into this function.

It would be much better to pass the mouse pixel position in as an integer, rather than passing the entire `SDL_Event` struct. An `SDL_MOUSEMOTION` event might store the x position at `event.motion.x`, but `SDL_MOUSEBUTTON_DOWN` and `SDL_MOUSEBUTTON_UP` will store it at `event.button.x`. Passing the position as an integer would also avoid the need for two separate functions for x and y.

We can also calculate the position directly instead of looping:

```
int pixelToBoardPos(int tileSize, int pixelPos) {
    return pixelPos / tileSize;
}
```

If we want to do bounds checking to ensure the mouse is over the board, we should probably do that before we pass the pixel position into this function.

---

### Load once, render every frame:

> ```
> void drawBoard(gc* graphics, int tileSize) { ... }
> void updatePieces(gc* graphics, int board[8][8], int tileSize, const char* spritePath[12]) { ... }
> ```

Both of these functions are doing something they *definitely* shouldn't do: loading textures from disk every single time they're called! Reading from (or writing to) disk is very slow.

We have an array of paths for the pieces that we create once at the start: `const char* spritePath[12] = { ... }`. After initializing SDL, we can easily create another array of `SDL_Texture*`s to hold all our images, and pass it into the functions that need it. We can load the background images for the squares in a similar way.

Note that we should be calling `SDL_RenderPresent()` only once per frame. i.e.:

```
// main loop:
while (1) {

    // input / update logic:
    ...

    // rendering:
    drawBoard(...);
    drawPieces(...);
    SDL_RenderPresent(graphics.renderer);
}
```

---

### Don't reuse variables:

> ```
> typedef struct GraphicsComponents {
>     SDL_Window* window;
>     SDL_Renderer* renderer;
>     SDL_Surface* surface;
>     SDL_Texture* texture;
>     SDL_Rect rect;
> }gc;
> ```

Lastly, note that it's unnecessary (and misleading) to keep and reuse the `surface`, `texture` and `rect` variables here. They should all be local variables inside the functions that need them.

Comment: Thanks for you feedback. I have another question after starting to over-haul this project and make these improvements. I'm now using an array of textures to hold my sprites, do I also need an array of rect's to copy the texture(s) to? or just one rect that moves depending on where I need my texture to be rendered?

Comment: Since the rect has to move every time, an array wouldn't help. It would be fine to create a local `SDL_Rect` variable for each `SDL_RenderCopy()` call. (You could instead create one rect with the appropriate size before the drawing loop, and change the position inside the loop, but it probably won't make much difference performance-wise).